# responsive website with javascript off-canvas-sidebar doesn't work on iPhone 4, 5, 6

Tags: javascript, css, iphone

I have a Website with a responsive menu. I tested it with Google Chrome on Android Mobile Phones with a maximum viewport width of 480px I can touch the "Hamburger"-Icon at the top left and the javascript off-canvas-sidebar swipes in. It also works on Desktop Mac with Safari.

But it doesn't work on iPhones (tested it with iPhone 4, 5, 6):

http://fadendaten.herokuapp.com/
(for test resize browser viewport to smaller than 480px width)

Does anyone know why and how to fix this?

Comment: It may work, not confirmed.. Add cursor:pointer; to that particular hamburger div.

Comment: It does not appear to do anything after tapping on my iPhone 5. Most common issue is the `z-index` value - try targetting the button with css and add `position` any other than static (default) and then add a ridiculously high `z-index` value to test it.